# what is the structure of the xml file (tags) of the wiki pages-articles dump file

Tags: tags, wiki

i thought that the wiki dump XML file TAGS will be like

```
<page>
<title>   </title>
<content>   </content>
</page>
<page>
<title>   </title>
<content>   </content>
</page>
```

in addition to other tags.
i managed to find the page and title tags, but i still can not find where  the main article is, in body tag, or content tag, or article tag, any help

Comment: is the tag <text></text>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main article will be inside tag `<page>`,then`<revision>` and inside them search for `<text>`